# Removing Tree Cover from DSM Before Creating Contours?

Tags: qgis, dem

[image]I am very new to QGIS and seem to be stuck.
I cannot figure out how to remove trees from my DSM (generated in Pix4D Cloud) in order to generate contours.
I have tried following various turorials; drawing digitized polygons around the trees, converting them to vectors, translating them, etc. and nothing seems to be working.
Can anyone help?

Comment: With a DSM I can't think of any way. Can you get the original point cloud file?(LAS, LAZ, E57, etc) Then you could use CloudCompare or LAStools to eliminate everything but ground points.

Comment: Yes, I have the LAS file. I have tried using LAStools but, when I try to split the PC, it stops the plugin and tells me to pay for it. I haven't used CloudCompare yet, though.

Comment: If your point cloud is classified, use LAS2LAS to "Keep Classification (2)". LAS2LAS is one of the "free" tools in LAStools. If your point cloud is not classified, then use the CSF Plug-in in CloudCompare.

Comment: The PC was unclassified, and I managed to separate the ground cover from tree/building cover, which is perfect. Thank you for the help.
I might be asking too much here, but do you know if I am able (in either software) to set a single point as a benchmark elevation? I haven't found any useful info online.